# Combining touchstone s2p files into a higher order snp file

Tags: rf, ads

I only have access to a 4 port VNA and have a 5(or more) port device. I was wondering how can one export several s2p/s4p files to combine it in a sNp (N=number of ports). I understand the math behind it, I was wondering if their is any utility that can do it quickly.

Right now, I do it using ADS, it takes time and, most irritating, requires ADS!
Since I work a lot with Wolfram Mathematica, I tough coding a script to do it but I can't believe I'm the first one with that issue. Do you have any quicker solutions? Thanks!